# How can I set a tokenizer in elasticsearch.yml config?

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

What is the proper syntax to set the Whitespace tokenizer instead of the standard one in `elasticsearch.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no analyzer has been specified during index time, it will look for an analyzer in the index settings called `default`.
If, there is no anaylzer like this - it will be defaulted to `standard` analyzer.

There is no way to change this behaviour (e.g. replace last fail option).

So, all you can do is to create index with `default` analyzer

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and is there a way to set the tokenizer of the default analyzer to whitespace, via the config file? I would like to have this as a persistent setting for all indexes created.

Comment: I’m afraid there is no way to do it in yml config file for all indices